# Select option and display content related to option with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

this is my first question and after grinding through several threads on here I am still completely lost and can't find a proper solution to my problem.

**What I want to do?**
A select Box with various options, each options is connected with a JQuery script which makes a related div visible when selected.

```
<center>    
<select onclick="changeview()">
    <option value="foo" id="location1" class="ticketbuttons my_active">Location 1</option>
    <option value="bar" id="location2" class="ticketbuttons">Location 2</option>
</select>
</center>
```

When you switch between the options, I want specific DIVs to appear or not appear by this script

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   jQuery( "#location1" ) function changeview() {
        jQuery(".changing_ticket").hide();
            jQuery("#loc1").fadeToggle();
            jQuery(".ticketbuttons").removeClass("my_active");
            jQuery("#location1").addClass("my_active");
            alert('Hello1');
     });
        
        jQuery( "#location2" ) function changeview() {
        jQuery(".changing_ticket").hide();
            jQuery("#loc2").fadeToggle();
            jQuery(".ticketbuttons").removeClass("my_active");
            jQuery("#location2").addClass("my_active");
            alert('Hello2');
     });
        
        jQuery( "#location3" ) function changeview() {
        jQuery(".changing_ticket").hide();
            jQuery("#loc3").fadeToggle();
            jQuery(".ticketbuttons").removeClass("my_active");
            jQuery("#location3").addClass("my_active");
            alert('Hello3');
     });
        
        jQuery( "#location4" ) function changeview() {
        jQuery(".changing_ticket").hide();
            jQuery("#loc4").fadeToggle();
            jQuery(".ticketbuttons").removeClass("my_active");
            jQuery("#location4").addClass("my_active");
            alert('Hello4');
     });
});
</script>
```

and last but not least the frontend output

```
<div id="loc1" class="change_ticket">Info about location 1</div>
<div id="loc2" class="change_ticket hidden">Info about location 2</div>
```

I have read about several options like change, onselect, on("change", function () .. and tested but nothin really worked for me.

Hope someone can help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this. Create a variable to store the value of the select dropdown **ID** & then check which option is selected and hide() the other values and display only the one necessary.

```
<!--  original dropdown. Replaced by updated for loops in PHP
<center>   
  <select id="changeEvent"> 
       <option value="1">Location 1</option>
       <option value="2">Location 2</option> 
       <option value="3">Location 3</option>
       <option value="4">Location 4</option>  
  </select>
</center>
-->

<!-- Changes made for dynamic option list-->
<!--Add a data attribute for counter to pass to your jquery loop--> 
<center>
<!-- Counter used for creating number of necessary options-->
<?php $counter = 20;?> 
<select id="changeEvent" data-counter-id="<?php echo $counter;?>">
    <?php
     for($i = 1;$i <= $counter; $i++){
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i;?>">Location <?php echo $i;?></option>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
 </select>
 </center>
```

Your divs use the same counter variable

```
   <!-- Original divs. Replaced by for loop to create dynamic option list
   <div id="loc1>" style="display:none;">Info about location 1</div>
   <div id="loc2>" style="display:none;">Info about location 2</div>
   <div id="loc3>" style="display:none;">Info about location 3</div> 
   <div id="loc4>" style="display:none;">Info about location 4</div>
   -->

  <?php
   for($x = 1;$x <= $counter; $x++){
  ?>   
    <div id="loc<?php echo $x?>" style="display:none;">Info about location <?php echo $x?></div>
  <?php
   }
  ?>
```

In your jQuery function you could add an on('change') event instead of inline on your select dropdown & grab the value of the Select option list and do a check to see which one was selected and display the appropriate DIV. Add a fadeIn() to the item you want to show()

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#changeEvent").on('change', function() { 

        /*Original code
           var options = $(this).val();
           if(options == '1'){
               $("#loc1).fadeIn('slow').show();
               $("#loc2).hide();
               $("#loc3).hide();
               $("#loc4).hide();
           }else if(options == '2'){
               $("#loc1).hide();
               $("#loc2).fadeIn('slow').show();
               $("#loc3).hide();
               $("#loc4).hide();
           }else if(options == '3'){
               $("#loc1).hide();
               $("#loc2).hide();
               $("#loc3).fadeIn('slow').show();
               $("#loc4).hide();
           }else{
               $("#loc1).hide();
               $("#loc2).hide();
               $("#loc3).hide();
               $("#loc4).fadeIn('slow').show();
           }
          
        */
        
        /* This will loop through options and display the selected*/
        var options = $(this).val();
        var counter = $(this).data("counter-id");

        for(let i = 1; i <= counter; i++){
            if(options != i){
                 $("#loc" + i).hide();
            }else{              
                $("#loc" + options).fadeIn('slow').show();
            }
        }
     });
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: This one definitely killed it and included even less ids/classes too - thanks a lot!

To learn one step further in this case, so when I have now 20 different locations I would assume that this could make the script run less effective? So I think it could make sense to parse value with the #ids or? like 1 = loc1, 2 = loc2 so I could just do one if loop like

If value 1 parse with loc1 and hide all other ids

What do you think? No need to write, just wanting to think further.

Comment: @theme_ are you using a backend scripting language to handle the returned values like PHP?

Comment: @theme_ so for example, if you use PHP, you would create a loop & counter for your dropdown, grab that value and run it in a loop and then check to see if that option has been selected and show or hide div based on selection. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: thanks a lot! 

One question further on carrying out your mentioned script when I have got an URL paramter like ?location=2 to pre-select an option (like when external people in a certain area see advertisement they get redirected directly to the option by url parameter) - How do I connect this to on('change') event? It does need to be something like if on(change) or on(pageload+val(urlparamater) then run function right?

Answer (score 0):

Try using onchange instead of onclick on the select tag

```
<select onchange="changeview()"></select>
```

or you could try putting ID on the select tag and do some jQuery

```
<select id="selectOption"></select>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('change','#selectOption', function () {
    // DO THINGS HERE
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for thinking into this! Basically used this from stuckfornow more cleaner code block. :)